# Setting date in Greek Locale

Tags: php, date, character

I insert in my database a date. But everytime I do that i see on the date field

```
    1st January, 1970
```

I tried to use the setLocal() function shown in the official php documentation as

```
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'greek');
```

but still have the same problem!

Here is my php code:

```
<?php 
//Newcastle 3 - 3 Man Utd
include("./init.php");

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

 $post_game = $_POST['game'];

 $time = strtotime($_POST['date']);
 //13 Δεκ 2016
 //$post_date = date('D, jS', $time) . ' of ' . date('F', $time);
 $post_date = date('jS F, Y',$time);
  setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'greek');


if($post_game==''){

    echo "<script>alert('Please fill in all fields')</script>";
    exit();
    }
else {

    $insert_game = "insert into last_game (game,date) values ('$post_game','$post_date')";

    $run_posts = mysqli_query($con,$insert_game); 

        echo "<script>alert('Post Has been Published!')</script>";

        echo "<script>window.open('index.php?last_game_details','_self')</script>";

    }

}

  ?>
```

Comment: maybe I'm failing but it looks that you set locale **after** formatting date/time...

Comment: Should you be using the language code 'el' instead of 'greek'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this first add lc_ctype then lc_time

```
include("./init.php");
// add this here
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'greek');
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'greek');
```

Comment: Ι still have the same problem.

Comment: Can you add it after include("./init.php");